# my discord bot doesn't speak on voice channel

Tags: node.js

I want my discord bot to say some data out loud on the voice channel, but I get an error that google is not a function, can you help me?

[image]

Comment: Please add you code as a Codesnipet not as an image

Comment: I really don't know how to do